# Sum all sub group last value by group

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following table:

```
ID | ITEM | GROUP_ID | VAL       | COST 
---+------+----------+-----------+-------
1  |  A   | 1        | 1         | 12     
2  |  B   | 1        | 2         | 12       
3  |  C   | 1        | 3         | 12    
4  |  D   | 1        | 4         | 13      
5  |  D   | 1        | 5         | 12    
6  |  E   | 2        | 1         | 17      
7  |  E   | 2        | 2         | 10     
8  |  E   | 2        | 3         | 11       
9  |  E   | 2        | 4         | 12      
10 |  F   | 2        | 5         | 15       
11 |  F   | 2        | 6         | 13      
12 |  F   | 2        | 7         | 11      
13 |  F   | 2        | 8         | 12
```

how to get the result as follow:

```
 GROUP_ID | VAL       | COST 
----------+-----------+-------
 1        | 15        | 48     
 2        | 36        | 24
```

The val is the sum by group id.
The cost is the sum of last value by item.

Comment: always include the rdbms name, sql server,  mySql ...etc

Comment: how in your sample  `cost = 48` ?

Comment: thx @Juan Carlos Oropeza remind...update flag..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    WITH LastRow (id)
    AS (
       SELECT MAX(id) 
       FROM TheTable
       GROUP BY item, group_id    
    )
    SELECT group_Id, SUM(val), SUM(CASE WHEN B.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE cost END)
    FROM TheTable A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN LastRow B ON A.id = B.id
    GROUP BY group_id
```

**EDIT:**
[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a93dc/27/0)

Thanks @Juan Carlos Oropeza for creating the SQL Fiddle test data

Comment: I think you need `group_id` or `id` or `item` on select part of the cte?

Comment: well you can test your query in my sqlfidle.

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` on postgres, oracle or sql server

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a93dc/19)**

```
WITH last_item as (    
    SELECT group_id, sum(cost) as sum_cost
    FROM (
        SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by item order by id desc) as rn 
        FROM Table1 t
        ) as t
   WHERE rn = 1
   GROUP BY t.group_id
), 
val_sum as (
    SELECT t.group_id, SUM(val) as sum_val
    FROM Table1 t
    GROUP BY t.group_id
)
SELECT v.group_id, v.sum_val, l.sum_cost
FROM val_sum v
INNER JOIN   last_item l
ON v.group_id = l.group_id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| group_id | sum_val | sum_cost |
|----------|---------|----------|
|        1 |      15 |       48 |
|        2 |      36 |       24 |
```